# Checking if an IPv4 address is valid

Tags: java

I am trying to write a basic program in Java that checks if an IP address is valid. I am trying to use no external classes other than the Scanner class and also no regular expressions.

My code, available at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f0f793f08bc391df8592)takes in 4 integers as input, one for each octet. I also have [this code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f4ed7b8f5331097ce73)which is a little more readable than the first but is longer.

My question is, is there any other way to implement this idea in significantly fewer lines, and if so, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: You could take the whole string in, split it by ".", ensure the length of the array is 4, and then loop over each item in the array and validate that it's a legit octet.  But in general, I think you can solve your current code by just looping 4 times and in each loop scan an octet, validate, and punt if the validation fails.  Removes a lot of code dupe.

Comment: I bet you could use a for loop.  There does seem to be quite a bit of duplicate code that looks similar.

Comment: I'm trying to use a for loop, but I get stuck when trying to declare a variable for each octet. I would need 4 different variables (for each octet), so how would I declare them in the loop?

Comment: @Kootling Declare them outside the loop, and use one of them for each iteration. You could check the value of the iterator to know which variable to use.

Answer (score 1):

While this code segment is a bit verbose, it is simple, self-descriptive, and has proven to be tight.

```
private static boolean isIPAddressValid(String ip) {    
    boolean result = true;
    int i = 0;
    int [] val = new int[4];

    if ((ip == null) || (ip.trim().length() == 0))
    {
        //null ip address entered
        result = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!(ip.contains(".")))
        {
            //no '.' found
            result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            String [] parts = ip.split("\\.");
            if (!(parts.length == 4))
            {
                //not 4 quadrants
                result = false;
            }
            else
            {
                for (String s : parts) { 
                    try {
                        val[i] = Integer.parseInt(s);
                        if ((val[i] < 0) || (val[i] > 255))
                        {
                            //this quadrant's value exceeds limits
                            result = false;
                        }
                        i++;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //failed to parse quadrant to an integer");
                        result = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

only some minor enhancements (i think your code looks **very good** - my opinio so far) it is clearly to read and all work blocks are properly to understand....

```
boolean isFailed = false;
if (first < 0 || first > 255) {
    System.out.println("Octet 1 is invalid");
    isFailed = true;
}
if (second < 0 || second > 255) {
    System.out.println("Octet 2 is invalid");
    isFailed = true;
}
if (third < 0 || third > 255) {
    System.out.println("Octet 3 is invalid");
    isFailed = true;
}
if (fourth < 0 || fourth > 255) {
    System.out.println("Octet 4 is invalid");
    isFailed = true;
}

if (!isFailed){
    System.out.println("IP Address: " + first + "." + second + "." + third + "." + fourth);
}
```

so i simply invert the order of printing - that saves you only that *big* check before...

Comment: I don't understand how this is different from the second gist I posted ([here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f4ed7b8f5331097ce73)). Doesn't this code just switch the values of the boolean in my original code?

Comment: it doesn't have this part `if (first >= 0 && first <= 255 && second >= 0 && second <= 255 && third >= 0 && third <= 255 && fourth >= 0 && fourth <= 255) {...` which was posted in your original code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f0f793f08bc391df8592 ...

Answer (score 0):

your approach was to can check each octet...

you can simply do this 4 times or write a method for it:

```
private static boolean check(int octet, int index){
    if (0xFF & octet < 256) return true;
    System.out.println("Octet "+index+" is invalid";
    return false;
}
```

and use this method in your main method

```
if (check(first,0) && check (second, 2) && check (third, 3) && check(fourth, 4) ){
    System.out.println("your ip is valid");
}
```

note - this only reveals the first invalid octet - if you want to check all you need another boolean

```
boolean result = check(first,0) && 
    check (second, 2) && 
    check (third, 3) && 
    check(fourth, 4); //reveals all errors
```

a totally different approach would be to use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29

```
try{
    /*InetAdress adress =*/ InetAdress.
        getByName(""+first+"."+second+"."+third+"."+forth)
    System.out.println("your ip is valid");
}catch (UnknownHostException e){
    //TODO represent that error message into a nice expression
    System.out.println("your ip is invalid");
}
```

but this as well doesn't provide information about that octet which is invalid...

(by the way - what **is** wrong with your code? it's fine, really!)

Answer (score 0):

I was just bored and wrote this regexp

```
public static boolean isValid(String ip) {
    boolean isvalid;

    isvalid = ip.matches(
            "(([0-9]|[0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9]*{0,2}|2[0-5][0-5]|0{0,3}).){3}" +
             "([0-9]|[0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9]*{0,2}|2[0-5][0-5]|0{0,3})"
    );

    return isvalid;
}
```

And it was tested on the following dataset:

```
String[] ips = {
        "0.0.0.0",
        "0.111.222.0",
        "0.0.0.000",
        "0.00.0.000",
        "1.1.1.1",
        "2.2.2.2",
        "12.13.14.15",
        "29.29.29.29",
        "99.99.000.1",
        "111.102.144.190",
        "255.255.199.199",
        "266.255.255.255", //inv
        "255.265.255.255", //inv 
        "255.255.258.255", //inv 
        "255.255.255.259", //inv 
        "299.100.110.255" //inv
    };
    for (String s : ips) {
        if (isValid(s) == false) {
            System.err.println(s + " is invalid");
        }
    }
```